# Compare data in two excels to third excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 3 excels A,B and C with some data as below.

Characteristics of data in Excel A,B

1. Each title is unique
2. For each title, there is a corresponding ID. Please find sample data below.

   ```
    Excel A                                     Excel B
    > > **New_Title**   **New_ID**         **Existing_Title** **Existing_ID**
    >   Title1            W-1                     Title3              W-3
    >   Title2            W-2                     Title4              W-4
   ```

   Excel C

   ```
    > > **IncidentTitle**                   
    >   Title1
        Title1
        Title1       
        Title2
        Title2      
        Title3
        Title4
   ```

Excel C can have multiple rows with same title.

I am trying to compare data in A, B to C and write ID column to excel C. So that for each row that  has same Title, it gets written with respective ID. For eg: Title1 is appeared 3 times in Excel C, so it's ID: W-1 has to be written thrice in the Excel C and so on. I have tried with some approaches but they were unsuccessful. Any help in identifying where I am going wrong is appreciated.

```
for i in range(length):
\\Omitted some lines of code here.
    for j in range(c_len): //length of excel C.
        Title = id_map.at[j, 'IncidentTitle']   //id_map is the dataframe containing the data of Excel C
        if Title == New_Title:
            Jira_ID.insert(j, New_ID)
        elif Title == Existing_Title:
            Jira_ID.insert(j, Existing_ID)
        else:
            continue // Can be any placeholder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the dataframes:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({
    'New_Title': ['Title1', 'Title2'],
    'New_ID': ['W-1', 'W-2'],
})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({
    'Existing_Title': ['Title3', 'Title4'],
    'Existing_ID': ['W-3', 'W-4'],
})

dfC = pd.DataFrame({
    'IncidentTitle': ['Title1', 'Title1', 'Title1', 'Title2', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4']
})
```

First we can *union* the `dfA` and `dfB` by `pd.concat`,

```
dfAB = pd.concat([
    dfA.rename(columns={'New_Title': 'Title', 'New_ID': 'ID'}),
    dfB.rename(columns={'Existing_Title': 'Title', 'Existing_ID': 'ID'}),
])

print(dfAB)

    Title   ID
0  Title1  W-1
1  Title2  W-2
0  Title3  W-3
1  Title4  W-4
```

Then one of the pandas ways to do your job is by `merge`, it finds matching keys among the two dataframes `dfC` and `dfAB`, where `'IncidentTitle'` is used for `dfC` and `'Title'` is used for `dfAB`, and in case there is a match it merges data from `dfAB` to `dfC` (this merging direction is by using `how='left'`)

```
dfC.merge(dfAB, left_on='IncidentTitle', right_on='Title', how='left').drop(columns='Title')
```

Final outcome:

```
  IncidentTitle   ID
0        Title1  W-1
1        Title1  W-1
2        Title1  W-1
3        Title2  W-2
4        Title2  W-2
5        Title3  W-3
6        Title4  W-4
```

Note that if you have duplicated Titles in `dfAB`, the outcome may not be as expected.